# overlap multiple user controls (div) without using position:absolute

Tags: html, css, asp.net, vb.net, user-controls

I already read many scenarios regarding overlapping divs but none is working with me. This is my current UI: [image]

and this is my partial aspx code:

```
            <table style="width:100%;">
                <tr style="width:100%;">                         
                   <td style="width:33.33%; vertical-align:top;"><uc1:statform runat="server" ERBedNumber="Bed1" TempHospNum="ER101" id="statform1" /></td> 
                   <td style="width:33.33%; vertical-align:top;"><uc1:statform runat="server" ERBedNumber="Bed2" TempHospNum="ER102" id="statform2" /></td> 
                   <td style="width:33.33%; vertical-align:top;"><uc1:statform runat="server" ERBedNumber="Bed3" TempHospNum="ER103" id="statform3" /></td>  
                </tr>                            
            </table>  


            <table style="width:100%;">
                <tr style="width:100%;">                         
                        <td style="width:33.33%; vertical-align:top;"><uc1:statform runat="server" ERBedNumber="Bed4" TempHospNum="ER104" id="statform4" /></td> 
                        <td style="width:33.33%; vertical-align:top;"><uc1:statform runat="server" ERBedNumber="Bed5" TempHospNum="ER105" id="statform5" /></td> 
                        <td style="width:33.33%; vertical-align:top;"><uc1:statform runat="server" ERBedNumber="Bed6" TempHospNum="ER106" id="statform6" /></td>  
                </tr>                            
                       </table>                  
            <table style="width:100%;">          
                <tr style="width:100%;">                                                           
                        <td style="width:33.33%; vertical-align:top; "><uc1:statform runat="server" ERBedNumber="Bed7" TempHospNum="ER107" id="statform7" /></td> 
                        <td style="width:33.33%; vertical-align:top; "><uc1:statform runat="server" ERBedNumber="Bed8" TempHospNum="ER108" id="statform8" /></td>  
                        <td style="width:33.33%; vertical-align:top; "><uc1:statform runat="server" ERBedNumber="Bed9" TempHospNum="ER109" id="statform9" /></td> 
                </tr>

             </table>   

            <table style="width:100%;">          
                <tr style="width:100%;">                                                           
                        <td style="width:33.33%; vertical-align:top; "><uc1:statform runat="server" ERBedNumber="Bed10" TempHospNum="ER110" id="statform10" /></td> 
                        <td style="width:33.33%; vertical-align:top; "><uc1:statform runat="server" ERBedNumber="Bed11" TempHospNum="ER111" id="statform11" /></td>  
                        <td style="width:33.33%; vertical-align:top; "><uc1:statform runat="server" ERBedNumber="Bed12" TempHospNum="ER112" id="statform12" /></td> 
                </tr>

             </table>  

        </asp:Panel>
```

But when the user control expands (when i click Close/Register Patient button) it will look like this:
[image]

Which is i don't like to happen. I want to overlap it on the other user controls and appear like this:

[image]

I also want to apply it on all of the Beds, not only for Bed 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out an answer to my question but it contradicts it because I placed a property position:absolute. I placed it in the css of my table in my user control, but it fixed my problem and it led me to my desired output.

```
.pnlUserControl{
padding:20px;
border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.8);
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
-moz-background-clip: content-box;
-webkit-background-clip: content-box;
background-clip:  content-box;
background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8); 
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 13px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 13px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
box-shadow: 0 0 13px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.3);

<%-- i added some css to display it on full screen
     to avoid clicking of other buttons --%>
position:absolute;
left:0;
top:0;
width:100%; 
height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using only CSS, id say for you to use `position: relative` making them relative to their parent.  From there... Just do `top:-50px` or `left: -37px` or whatever values you need.  After setting to relative just use **top, bottom, left and right** to adjust its position either *position/negative*

Comment: do i have other choice rather than css? how can i do it in js or jquery?